# Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range error?

Tags: c++

I keep getting the following error:

`Unhandled exception at 0x74BDD8A8 in FileName.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x004FA55C.`

I've done some searching but I was not able to solve this problem.  I did narrow it down to the fact that the `out of range` error is coming from my `string fdata` variable. Here is my code where error/exception occurs:

```
void MyClass::MyMethod10()
{
    string fdata;
    char num[100];
    int i = 0,k=0;
    unsigned int m,j=0;

    inputFile.open("sec1.txt", ios::in);
    inputFile >> fdata;
    while (j<fdata.length())
    {
       while (fdata.at(j) != '+')
       {
          if (fdata.at(j) != '*' && j<fdata.length())
          {
            num[k] = fdata.at(j);
            k++;
          }
          else
          {
             num[k] = '\0';
             m = atoi(num);
             //cout << m << endl;
             MyMethod22(m);
             k = 0;
          }
          j++;
       }
       MyMethod22(43);
       j++;  
   }
   inputFile.close();
   outputFile.open("sec2.txt", ios::out);
   while (i<index)
   {
     outputFile << (char)data[i];
     i++;
   }
   outputFile.close();
   CleanBuffer();
}
```

The `sec1.txt` file contains the following data

```
25750*23084*57475*15982*+57475*15982*+13364*15982*26260*+48840*32397*13364*15982*57475*11371*21876*+25197*
```

In the `while()` loop section my program is able to read the data correctly from the file.  The problem/error/exception occurs at the point where my program takes in the last number from the file.  I am guessing the problem is in the `while()` loop, but I am not able to figure out what's wrong. All I was able to do was to narrow down the error to `string fdata` being out of range after it reads the last number from the file.  I was wondering if anyone can help me to solve this or suggest something which I might have missed?

Comment: MSVC++ has an option in the debug menu, "break on exceptions".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual problem you have is here:

```
   while (fdata.at(j) != '+')
   {
      ...
      j++;
   }
```

Note that you increment `j`, and try to read `j`-th character before you check if `j` is in range. To fix it, change it like this:

```
   while (j < fdata.size() && fdata.at(j) != '+')
   {
      ...
      j++;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you @ Ishamael and @mathematician1975 =. My problem is solved.